# Avoid memory leaks sending jquery selectors as constructors parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

I builded some views without using MVC framework. Only jQuery and JavaScript.
I have more or less, the next construction:

```
function LeWildConstructor ($selector) {
   $selector.find('anElement').bind(function () {
     ...
   });
}

$(function () {
  window.wildConstructor = new LeWildConstructor($('.container'));
});
```

An soft architect told me this construction is potentially leaking if the page continue open for a while.

He suggest do something like:

```
function LeWildConstructor () {
   var $selector = $('.container')
   $selector.find('anElement').bind(function () {
     ...
   });
}

$(function () {
  window.wildConstructor = new LeWildConstructor();
});
```

I think both approches are the same.

I understand after the ready document the constructor call once, and the parameter sended one time, and jQuery is lazy, once I send the node element, doesn't call anymore each time I reference `$selector` inside of the constructor.

But I'm not sure if I'm missing other practices than can generate a possible leak.

Comment: That architect is too soft. Get a harder architect. This sounds like rubbish, does he have any evidence to back his claims?

Comment: Sounds liked some miscommunication going on. Ask for a better explanation of the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you don't assign it to a variable I don't see why there would be any leaking, but consider this code:

```
$(function () {
  var something = $('.container');
  window.wildConstructor = new LeWildConstructor();
});
```

This closure would not be collected until you delete the global variable, so it's true that the other approach avoids 1 reference to be "leaked". Now, there is probably no difference between having 1 extra jQuery selector in memory on any page, specially if it's called just a few times.

I'm not sure how jQuery works, but this seems to be an array of objects (references) and that should be ultra lightweight to have floating in memory.

TL;DR Although relevant, I think his consideration is pointless and false in this specific case.

*Edited after a bit more of thinking
Edited again to clarlify after t.niese comment*

Comment: I don't see a `var something = $('.container'); window.wildConstructor = new LeWildConstructor();` in the code of the OP, just a `window.wildConstructor = new LeWildConstructor( $('.container') );`.

Comment: "This closure would not be collected until you delete the global variable, so it's true that the other approach avoids 1 reference to be "leaked"." --- this is simply wrong. An object that `something` holds a reference to will be marked as a garbage as soon as the interpreter goes out of this anonymous function scope.